# Prove $n+\left(-1\right)^n\ge \frac{n}{2}$ is true for $n\ge 2$ using induction

Tags: induction, proof-explanation

I'm trying to prove $n+\left(-1\right)^n\ge \dfrac{n}{2}$ is true for all natural numbers $n \ge 2$ via induction. The base case is trivial as
$$2+(-1)^2 \ge \frac{1}{2}(2)$$
$$3 \ge 1.$$
For the induction step, I'm looking at $$(n+1) + (-1)^{n+1} = n+1+(-1)(-1)^n$$
$$\ge \frac{1}{2}n +1-2\cdot(-1)^n$$
This is where I get stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you prove $n-1\ge\frac n2$ for $n\ge2$?

Comment: @AnginaSeng yeah I can prove that using induction fairly easily

Comment: Great, now you have to find out how $n-1$ and $n+(-1)^n$ are connected!

Comment: @Stockfish So should I split up the expression into two cases, one where n is even and the other when n is odd?

Comment: Hmm that's an overkill, recall that you want to prove an inequality ...

Comment: @Stockfish I see, so I only have to look at the case that would be the smallest and say that the expression would be greater than or equal to that case

Comment: @JamesA that is where I was stuck; trying to get the RHS of the inequality to be $\frac{n+1}{2}$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110694/discussion-between-shellg44-and-james-a).

Answer (score 1):

What Angina Seng hinted in comment is:
$$n+(-1)^n\ge n-1\ge \frac n2 \iff n-\frac n2\ge 1 \iff n\ge 2.$$
To continue your line of thought, you must prove:
$$n+1+(-1)^{n+1}\ge \frac{n+1}2 \iff \frac n2\ge (-1)^n-\frac 12 \iff \\
\frac n2\ge 1\ge (-1)^n-\frac12.$$

Comment: What is your point?

Answer (score 1):

$$p(1):n=2 \to  2+(-1)^2\geq  \frac 22\\p(n):n+(-1)^{n}\geq \frac{n}{2}\\p(n+1):n+1+(-1)^{n+1}\geq \frac{n+1}{2}$$ divide into two cases (n=even- odd)
first case $n=even=2k ,k\geq 1$
$$n=even=2k \to p(n):2k+1\geq k\\p(n+1):2k+1+(-1)^{2k+1}\geq \frac{2k+1}{2}\\2k\geq k+\frac12 \checkmark (w.r.t. k\geq1)$$
second case $n=odd=2k+1,k\geq 1$
$$n=odd=2k+1 \to p(n):2k+1+(-1)^{2k+1}\geq \frac{2k+1}{2}\\p(n+1):2k+1+1+(-1)^{2k+2}\geq \frac{2k+2}{2}\\2k+3\geq k+1 \checkmark (w.r.t. k\geq1)$$

Comment: If we had to divide it into even-odd case then we wouldn't need of induction. So can you do it without this even-odd consideration?